# Dot appearing before namespace declaration C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to add a Web Reference (WCF) in an Android project. After I add the web reference when I try to declare my 'using ...'

```
using .CryptoMessengerClientDroid.SVC;
```

it doesn't find it. When I look in the Object Browser I get the following:

[image: object browser]

When i try to add the namespace like it is with the dot[.] beofre the name, of course it gives me an error.

I didn't encounter this before. Any suggestions would be apprecieted. Thanks

Comment: You are declarnig the class incorrectly. Please share your code.

Comment: @KobyDouek what code do you want me to share ? :)

Comment: Why are you writing `Using .NamespaceName` ?

Comment: When you are refering to a namepsace you added a reference to, you should write `using Namespace.Class.... etc`

Comment: Because the IntelliTrace is suggesting me that and as you see in the object broswer that is the name of web reference that I added...

Comment: hmmm... Very strange. Are you sure that is the name of the namespace? Nothing "above" it in the Object Explorer ?

Comment: That is the namespace because I have used it in other project WPF but as a service reference and it's working perfectly. But in android I can use only Web reference, so maybe it is something wrong with the web reference...